# Incidence matrix not reproducing the graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I am trying to reproduce the graph from an incidence matrix. For eg i have
`Graph[{1 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 2 -> 4, 2 \[DirectedEdge] 3, 
  3 \[DirectedEdge] 4, 4 \[DirectedEdge] 1}, VertexLabels -> "Name"]`
The graph looked like this [image: graph1]

I found out the incident matrix for the above one and i again used the "IncidenceGraph" to reproduce the graph. But the two graphs are not the same.
The graph looked like this 
[image: graph2]
Why is this so? I am using Mathematica version 10.2

Comment: "I found out the incident matrix for the above one" - how does it compare to the result of `IncidenceMatrix[]`?

Answer (score 3):

The issue here is that for `IncidenceMatrix`

> The vertices $v_i$ are assumed to be in the order given by `VertexList[g]` and the edges $e_j$ are assumed to be in the order given by `EdgeList[g]`.

So let's look at the order of the vertices in your graph,

```
g = Graph[{1 \[DirectedEdge] 2, 2 -> 4, 2 \[DirectedEdge] 3, 
   3 \[DirectedEdge] 4, 4 \[DirectedEdge] 1}, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
VertexList@g
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

> `{1, 2, 4, 3}`

They are not in numeric order, but when you make an `IncidenceGraph` the original vertex list from `g` is not passed, and so they are relabeled in numeric order

```
VertexList@IncidenceGraph@IncidenceMatrix@g
```

> `{1, 2, 3, 4}`

The solution is simply to use the 2-argument form of `IncidenceGraph` and pass the `VertexList` as the first argument

```
IncidenceGraph[VertexList@g, IncidenceMatrix[g], 
 VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]